# Removing hyphens in http but preserving hyphenated words in corpus

Tags: r, regex, stemming, punctuation, hyphenation

I am trying to modify a stemming function that is able to 1) remove hyphens in http (that appeared in the corpus) but, meanwhile, 2) preserve hyphens that appeared in meaningful hyphenated expressions (e.g., time-consuming, cost-prohibitive, etc.).
I actually asked similar questions a few months ago on a different [question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115193/remove-punctuation-but-keep-hyphenated-phrases-in-r-text-cleaning), the code looks like this:

```css
# load stringr to use str_replace_all
require(stringr)

clean.text = function(x)
{
  # remove rt
  x = gsub("rt ", "", x)
  # remove at
  x = gsub("@\\w+", "", x)
  x = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", x)
  x = gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", x)
  # remove http
  x = gsub("http\\w+", "", x)
  x = gsub("[ |\t]{2,}", "", x)
  x = gsub("^ ", "", x)
  x = gsub(" $", "", x)
  x = str_replace_all(x, "[^[:alnum:][:space:]'-]", " ")
  #return(x)
}

# example
my_text <- "accident-prone"
new_text <- clean.text(text)
new_text
[1] "accidentprone"
```

but could not get satisfactory answer, I then shifted my attention to other projects until resuming to work on this. It appears that the `"[^[:alnum:][:space:]'-]"` in the last line of the code block is the culprit that also removed `-` from the non-http part of corpus.

I could not figure out how to achieve our desired outputs, it will be very appreciated if someone could offer their insights on this.

Comment: Try replacing `str_replace_all(x, "[^[:alnum:][:space:]'-]", " ")` with `gsub("\\b-\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|[^[:alnum:][:space:]'-]", " ", x, perl=TRUE)` or - to keep the pattern Unicode aware - `gsub("(*UCP)\\b-\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|[^\\w\\s'-]|_", " ", x, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: It still gives the same result.

Comment: Ok, replace `x = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", x)` with `x = gsub("(?!-)[[:punct:]]", "", x, perl=TRUE)`. Note that still you may get rid of `stringr` by replacing the `str_replace` line with `x = gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]'-]", " ", x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual culprit is the `[[:punct:]]` removing pattern as it matches `-` anywhere in the string.

You may use

```
clean.text <- function(x)
{
  # remove rt
  x <- gsub("rt\\s", "", x)
  # remove at
  x <- gsub("@\\w+", "", x)
  x <- gsub("\\b-\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|[[:punct:]]", "", x, perl=TRUE)
  x <- gsub("[[:digit:]]+", "", x)
  # remove http
  x <- gsub("http\\w+", "", x)
  x <- gsub("\\h{2,}", "", x, perl=TRUE)
  x <- trimws(x)
  x <- gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]'-]", " ", x)
  return(x)
}
```

Then,

```
my_text <- "  accident-prone  http://www.some.com  rt "
new_text <- clean.text(my_text)
new_text 
## => [1] "accident-prone"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/fRPXxZ).

Note:

- `x = gsub("^ ", "", x)` and `x = gsub(" $", "", x)` can be replaced with `trimws(x)`
- `gsub("\\b-\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|[[:punct:]]", "", x, perl=TRUE)` removes any punctuation BUT hyphens in between word chars (you may adjust this further in the part before `(*SKIP)(*F)`)
- `gsub("[^[:alnum:][:space:]'-]", " ", x)` is a base R equivalent for `str_replace_all(x, "[^[:alnum:][:space:]'-]", " ")`.
- `gsub("\\h{2,}", "", x, perl=TRUE)` remove any 2 or more horizontal whitespaces. If by `"[ |\t]{2,}"` you meant to match any 2 or more whitespaces, use `\\s`  instead of `\\h` here.

Comment: Thank you so much for this very detailed explanation! I will read more on `gsub`.